# CSS making boxes too big and taking up all the required space

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I'm using Django's HTML scripting to iterate through a list of tags from a ManyToManyField for an article. Getting the information works, but the actual sizing of the borders around the tags ends up being all wrong. The boxes are absurdly big. The titles also aren't where I want them to be, though that is on hold.

The CSS is a combination of custom CSS and [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) (yes, I know that's a bad practice, but I'm lazy).

HTML:

```html
{% extends 'head.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <h1 class="flex items-center justify-center text-6xl">Articles</h1>
    <br>
    {% if articles %}
        <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
            <div class="posts">
                {% for article in articles %}
                    <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}">
                        <div class="article_box">
                            <span>{{ article.article_title }}</span>
                            <div>
                                {% for tag in article.article_tags.all %}
                                    <div class="tag">{{tag}}</div>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

CSS:

```css
.posts {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: grid;
  gap: 4rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  padding-left: 12rem;
  padding-right: 12rem;
}

.posts div {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.article_box {
  width: 3/12;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.tag {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20%;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0.15rem;
}

.tags {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 3/12;
}
```

Result:

[image]

I want for the tags to be on the line under the title with the borders of the tags surrounding them only to the size of the text. I want the tags next to one another unless they go outside of the article box, in which case they go to the next line. I also want all of them to be at the bottom of the article box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.posts div { aspect-ratio: 1; }` this causing the problem. Do it like `.posts > div { ... }` all direct child divs of parent `.posts` div, or `.article_box { aspect-ratio: 1; }` if you need it. And make `.tag` a **inline-block**.

`!` One thing. I have never seen something like `width: 3/12;` follow [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) to know how a value should be to "width" property.

Comment: Thanks. `width: 3/12` is not the way I ususally write things, it was a mistake because I wrote w-3/12 so many times already due to part of this using TailwindCSS and w-3/12 being a Tailwind thing.

Comment: If this answer is helpful to you, pls mark this answer as accepted or upvote it.